# How to add xtype as item to a dynamically created tab in Extjs tabpanel

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have created a ExtJS tabpanel which will have 7 tabs and based on condition I want to make a tab active and bind bind data (xtype) dynamically.

I would like to know how we can add xtype to a tab dynamically. Below is tabpanel code.

```
    var empTabPanel= new Ext.tab.Panel({
            id: 'emptabpanel',
            width: '100%',
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [{
                    title: 'Personal Details',
                    border: 0,
                    id: 'PERSONAL_DETAILS'
                },{
                    title: 'Department Details',
                    border: 0,
                    id: 'DEP_DETAILS'
                },{
                    title: 'Leave Details',
                    border: 0,
                    id: 'LEAVE_DETAILS'
                }]
        });
```

I have want to add xtype for Department Details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to add new items to the department tab, you can simply add them as you add to any panel or container.

Ext.getCmp('DEP_DETAILS').add({ xtype: 'label', text: 'Hi' });

But you cannot change the xtype of an existing item. You can however add/remove them.

Answer (score 2):

Binding the xtype is not possible because the xtype cannot be changed at runtime. Once the component has been created with a certain xtype, it cannot change anymore.

What you have to do is make multiple tabs, one for each possible xtype, and show/hide the tabs as appropriate, or create/delete tabs at runtime using `Ext.create`.